# regularization path for SVM in python

Tags: scikit-learn, regularized

I have looked around to find a R's [svmpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761240/how-to-figure-out-optimal-c-gamma-parameters-in-libsvm) equivalent for sklearn or python. Did I overlook it or do I need to go with R for this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik there is no path algorithm. The usual thing would be to do a grid search over possible C. There will be a path algorithm for l2 loss in the linear case in scikit-learn soon (possibly this week).